# Reducing Dimension of datasets and implementation

Tags: java, c, matlab, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

To reach the `state of the art` of [dimension reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_reduction) I'd like to know if  there is  an implementation no matter if it is pseudocode, c, java, matlab... of several algorithms or if there is some project that has some of them implemented

for example I know that for PCA we can use matlab's svd() function... but a full script or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FastICA](http://research.ics.tkk.fi/ica/fastica/) is a very good package for doing this sort of thing, and it's available in C++, R, Python, and MATLAB. I have used the matlab version of this package; it's simple to use and produces good output.